# Why does Beau have to keep his apartment complex door open with a telephone book?

Tags: beau-is-afraid

In the movie, ***Beau is afraid***, Beau takes a pill without water when his water supply is cut out; he runs out of his apartment complex, using a telephone book to keep the complex door not close and runs to a store to buy a bottle of water.

I am wondering why would Beau need to use a book to keep the door not close, what happens to his keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

His keys were stolen. This apparently includes his key to the building entrance, which he then needs to prop open *or else it will shut and lock him out.*

The script offers us a little more exposition.

> INT. BATHROOM - CONTINUOUS
>
> Beau grabs his FLOSS from the medicine cabinet and runs back
> toward the front door, but - HE FREEZES.
>
> THE KEY IS NO LONGER IN THE DOOR! His suitcase is also missing.
> Beau steps into the HALL. Looks left and right. It’s EMPTY.
>
> [snip]
>
> Beau has come downstairs to the LOBBY. He stares out the
> front door’s window at the teeming carpet of homeless thugs
> (blocking his trajectory to the convenience store).
>
> Beau fights a rush of oncoming PANIC, but then - no - he
> swallows his fear, and **he picks up a PHONE BOOK. Beau uses
> the book as a WEDGE for the building’s door**, and then--